# (My)SQL in Flex - any good libraries?

Tags: sql, mysql, apache-flex

I need to develop a small Flex application that needs to access a MySQL database. Since I have little experience in server-side Java, PHP programming I would prefer to use a library/framework that allows me to write SQL queries in ActionScript/MXML.

After a bit of research, I have come across two 3rd party libraries, [AS3FlexDB](http://code.google.com/p/as3flexdb/)(free) and Adobe Flex Connector for MySQL(45$). Initial tests with AS3FlexDB are promising, but I'm a bit afraid that I'll start to work on the project only to find out that I need a full-fledged back-end after all.

Do any of you have experience with these tools? If so, are they stable enough for production? Are there any such libraries for other relational databases(PostgreSQL in particular)?

Thank you!

Lawrence

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[this](http://www.adobe.com/cfusion/exchange/index.cfm?event=extensionDetail&loc=en_us&extid=1880524) and [CRUD like this](http://ted.onflash.org/2007/09/flex-3beta-2-crud-wizard-for-aspnet-php.php) and [read this](http://www.ryancampbell.com/2007/03/16/mysql-access-in-adobe-flex/)
[AS SQL Lib](http://asql.mooska.pl/) and [another one CRUD](http://flexcrud.riaforge.org/)
[and final happiness](http://www.flashcommunicationserver.com/cfusion/exchange/index.cfm?searchfield=Flex+MySQL&search_exchange=15&search_category=-1&search_license=&search_rating=&search_platform=0&search_pubdate=&num=25&startnum=1&event=search&sticky=true&sort=0&rnav_dummy_tmpfield=&Submit=)

Answer (score 1):

Flex is a UI Framework and is not designed for database interaction.  I strongly recommend you reconsider the approach and learn a server side language.  You'll thank yourself in the long run.

that said, another option is [FlexSQL](http://webscripts.softpedia.com/script/Database-Tools/FlexSQL-40353.html).  This is the first time I've heard of the two you mentioned.

I have no idea why people keep building these libraries.  It's like trying to use a screwdriver and nails together.  It is, in theory possible but better tools exist.

Comment: I realize that I will eventually have to learn a server-side language and look forward to that, but I need to develop a prototype in a few days for this project, thus the dreaded shortcut. 

Thanks for the tips!

Comment: If it is just a prototype; prototype it with fake data.  I strongly encourage against going down the route you're going down.  is it quicker to drive in a nail with a screwdriver?  Or to learn how to use a hammer?

Comment: I will definitely consider learning PHP if the prototype gets picked up and evolves into a real app. I will have to see if "faking data" is acceptable at this stage. Thanks again!

Comment: go to the side of AMF serialization and imho BlazeDS too, cause using java you'll save your time. :)

Answer (score 0):

I agree that server-side db interaction is the way to go, but nobody has mentioned the possibility of web services.  Use [this article](http://davidwalsh.name/web-service-php-mysql-xml-json) to create a number of web services that your flex client can connect to directly.